# Unable to create virtual environment with virtualenv or pipenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, virtualenv, pipenv

I am trying to create a virtual env for my flask project. However I tried using both pipenv and virtual env, but both method results in an error. I suspect that it is due to the path.

When I input `pipenv shell`, this is the log

```
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Pipfile: C:\Users\Yk\Pipfile
Using C:\Users\Yk\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe (3.7.6) to create virtualenv…
[==  ] Creating virtual environment...The path C:\Users\Yk\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe (from --python=C:\Users\Yk\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe) does not exist

Failed creating virtual environment
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "C:\Users\Yk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 390, in shell
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       pypi_mirror=state.pypi_mirror,
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "C:\Users\Yk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 2156, in do_shell
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       three=three, python=python, validate=False, pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "C:\Users\Yk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 574, in ensure_project
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "C:\Users\Yk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 506, in ensure_virtualenv
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       python=python, site_packages=site_packages, pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "C:\Users\Yk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pipenv\core.py", line 935, in do_create_virtualenv
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       extra=[crayons.blue("{0}".format(c.err)),]
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:
Failed to create virtual environment.
```

A empty pipfile is created

When I try to use Virtual Env `virtualenv env`, this is the log:

```
Using base prefix 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0'
New python executable in C:\Users\Yk\DOCUME~1\Code\WEBDEV~1\Flask\TESTPR~1\env\Scripts\python.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Yk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Yk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 870, in main
    symlink=options.symlink,
  File "C:\Users\Yk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1162, in create_environment        
    install_python(home_dir, lib_dir, inc_dir, bin_dir, site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink)
  File "C:\Users\Yk\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 1532, in install_python
    shutil.copyfile(executable, py_executable)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\shutil.py", line 120, in 
copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\Yk\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python.exe'
```

I have tried unistalling and reinstalling both modules.
I am using python 3.7.

How can i solve this error and use Pipenv? Thank you!

Comment: Did you add the right `virtualenv` path in environment variables.

Comment: Yup. I can run python and virtualenv from console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check your PATH for python execution or try with this command;

```
pipenv --rm
pipenv install
```

It might work, from your error code it will not detect python thats the problem

Comment: I am able to run python from my console. So python is in the path. Could it be that the name of the folder is too long?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so basically I reinstalled python. I suspected that it had to do with path, but i couldnt debug it after many hours.

Before i uninstalled though, it is important to remember the modules. So I did

```
pip freeze --local >pipfreeze.txt
```

After reinstalling, 
`pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall -r pipfreeze.txt` at the same directory